# Android - Removing space between TableLayout Rows

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to remove between the Button "0" and the Button "1". My goal is it to have the same space between them as the Button "X".
[UI result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxGCl.png)

These solutions did not work:

[How to remove space between two rows in Tablelayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668751/how-to-remove-space-between-two-rows-in-tablelayout)

[How to reduce space between two rows of Table Layout for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837877/how-to-reduce-space-between-two-rows-of-table-layout-for-android?rq=1)

Also, the Button "X" should span over both rows, which it only does, when i put in a bigger `textSize`.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0sp"
                android:padding="0sp">
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_margin="2sp"
                    />
            </TableRow>
            
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="0sp"
                android:padding="0sp">
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_margin="2sp"
                    />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="0sp"
            android:padding="0sp">
            <TableRow>
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="X"
                    android:layout_margin="2sp"
                    />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your approach with the nested `TableLayout` and failed to remove space completely. Button properties `insetTop` and `insetBottom` removed some space though. You can use a different approach using less nested layouts:

[image: Table layout without a space]

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:text="X" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
With `insetBottom` and `insetTop` i finally got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <TableRow>

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="0sp">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="0" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="0sp">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:layout_width="0sp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="1" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```